# Using Entity Framework 5.0 map relationship between parent and children when ID are Guids with newsequentialid()

Tags: entity-framework-5, foreign-key-relationship, newsequentialid

I have two classes with a one to many relationship.

```
public partial class Client
{
    public Client()
    {
        this.Client_Local = new HashSet<Client_Local>();
    }

    public System.Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Client_Local> Client_Local { get; set; }
}

public partial class Client_Local
{
    public System.Guid LocalGuid { get; set; }
    public System.Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public string CultureID { get; set; }
    public string LocalName { get; set; }

    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping classes are:

```
class ClientMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Client>
{
    public ClientMapping()
    {
        this.HasKey(entity => entity.Guid); //As newsequentialid()
        this.ToTable("Client");

        this.Property(entity => entity.Guid).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}

class Client_LocalMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Client_Local>
{
    public Client_LocalMapping()
    {
        this.HasKey(entity => entity.LocalGuid); // as As newsequentialid()
        this.ToTable("Client_Local");

        this.Property(entity => entity.LocalGuid).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.HasRequired<Client>(e => e.Client).WithMany(p => p.Client_Locals).HasForeignKey<Guid>(c => c.Guid);
    }
}
```

I can create new instances of client class and save them to the database successfully. But when I try and add a Client_Local class and save it to the database I get "A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'Guid'.".

The key fields are generated in sql as newsequentialid for performance reasons. And there is a foreign key relationship between Client_Local.Guid and Client.Guid.

Retrieving data from the database works with the above mapping classes.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.